# (solved) WordPress Site not loading properly

Tags: php, server

I initially intended for this post to fix the problem where the word press admin site was loading in the google chrome but not in firefox. This problem stemmed from php not being updated and was fixed by following [this guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/nginx-http-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta-server/); i.e. it was because php either wasn't installed or wasn't fully up to date. To update after doing the aforementione guide..

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

old post stuff, I thought there was an issue but I guess it was displaying properly.

---

local WordPress site doesn't load properly:

[image: weirdly not loading properly]

There are no errors from apache or wordpress debugging. WordPress is telling me to update my php but according to the current php version it's up to date. The apache2 server has been purged and reinstalled and all features.

I've done my due diligence; I don't know what could cause the problem but here's a bunch of debugging info...

Version Details

```
# (not a command but from wordpress site)
WordPress 5.4.2 running Twenty Twenty theme.
WordPress Running PHP version: 7.1.33-

$ php -v
PHP 7.2.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 08:27:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2020-03-13T12:26:16
```

[lots of details about server and packages / versions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y8qOg6k_MddSNZIYi25FWA4Uz48TCXKx/view?usp=sharing)

Apache server status:

```
(base) alita@alita-xps:/var/www/html$ sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-15 19:50:09 CDT; 3min 5s ago
  Process: 31300 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31262 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31305 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 31309 (apache2)
    Tasks: 9 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─31309 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31310 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31311 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31312 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31313 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31314 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31315 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─31316 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─31317 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jun 15 19:50:09 alita-xps systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 15 19:50:09 alita-xps systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Apache packages:

```
(base) alita@alita-xps:/var/www/html$ dpkg -l "*apache*"
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-====================================================
ii  apache2                 2.4.29-1ubuntu4. amd64            Apache HTTP Server
un  apache2-api-20120211    <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  apache2-api-20120211-op <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  apache2-bin             2.4.29-1ubuntu4. amd64            Apache HTTP Server (modules and other binary files)
ii  apache2-data            2.4.29-1ubuntu4. all              Apache HTTP Server (common files)
un  apache2-doc             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  apache2-suexec-custom   <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  apache2-suexec-pristine <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  apache2-utils           2.4.29-1ubuntu4. amd64            Apache HTTP Server (utility programs for web servers
un  apache2.2-bin           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  apache2.2-common        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  libapache2-mod-dacs     <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  libapache2-mod-passenge <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  libapache2-mod-php      <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.1   7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apach
rc  libapache2-mod-php7.2   7.2.24-0ubuntu0. amd64            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apach
un  mono-apache-server2     <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  mono-apache-server4     <none>           <none>           (no description available)
```

php packages:

```
(base) alita@alita-xps:/var/www/html$ dpkg -l "*php*"
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                    Version          Architecture     Description
+++-=======================-================-================-====================================================
un  libapache2-mod-php      <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  libapache2-mod-php7.1   7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apach
rc  libapache2-mod-php7.2   7.2.24-0ubuntu0. amd64            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apach
ii  php                     1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (defau
un  php-amqp                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-apcu                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-apcu-bc             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-ast                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-bz2                 1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              bzip2 module for PHP [default]
un  php-calendar            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-cli                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-common              2:76+ubuntu18.04 all              Common files for PHP packages
un  php-console-getopt      <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-crypt-gpg           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-ctype               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-curl                1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              CURL module for PHP [default]
un  php-dom                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-exif                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-fileinfo            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-fpm                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-ftp                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-gd                  1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              GD module for PHP [default]
un  php-geoip               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-gettext             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-gmagick             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-gmp                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-iconv               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-igbinary            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-imagick             3.4.4-4+ubuntu18 amd64            Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
un  php-json                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-libsodium           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-mbstring            1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              MBSTRING module for PHP [default]
un  php-mcrypt              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-memcache            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-memcached           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-mongodb             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-msgpack             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-mysql               1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              MySQL module for PHP [default]
un  php-mysqli              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-mysqlnd             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-opcache             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-pdo                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-pdo-mysql           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-pear                1:1.10.8+submodu all              PEAR Base System
un  php-pear-frontend-gtk   <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-pear-frontend-web   <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-phar                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-php-gettext         1.0.12-0.1       all              read gettext MO files directly, without requiring an
ii  php-phpseclib           2.0.9-1          all              implementations of an arbitrary-precision integer ar
un  php-posix               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-radius              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-readline            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-recode              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-redis               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-rrd                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-seclib              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-shmop               <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-simplexml           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-smbclient           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-sockets             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-ssh2                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-structures-graph    <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-sysvmsg             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-sysvsem             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-sysvshm             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-tcpdf               6.2.13+dfsg-1ubu all              PHP class for generating PDF files on-the-fly
un  php-tidy                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-tokenizer           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-uploadprogress      <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-uuid                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-wddx                <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-xdebug              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-xml                 1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP [d
un  php-xml-util            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-xmlreader           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-xmlrpc              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-xmlwriter           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php-xsl                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php-zip                 1:7.2+60ubuntu1  all              Zip module for PHP [default]
un  php-zmq                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php5.6-common           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php5.6-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php5.6-json             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.0-common           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.0-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1                  7.1.33-16+ubuntu all              server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metap
un  php7.1-calendar         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-cgi              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-cli              7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting langu
ii  php7.1-common           7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            documentation, examples and common module for PHP
un  php7.1-ctype            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-dom              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-exif             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-fileinfo         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-fpm              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-ftp              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-gd               7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            GD module for PHP
un  php7.1-gettext          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-iconv            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-json             7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mcrypt           7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            libmcrypt module for PHP
ii  php7.1-mysql            7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            MySQL module for PHP
un  php7.1-mysqli           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-mysqlnd          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-opcache          7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            Zend OpCache module for PHP
un  php7.1-pdo              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-pdo-mysql        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-phar             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-posix            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-readline         7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            readline module for PHP
ii  php7.1-recode           7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            recode module for PHP
un  php7.1-shmop            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-simplexml        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-sockets          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-sysvmsg          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-sysvsem          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-sysvshm          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-tidy             7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            tidy module for PHP
un  php7.1-tokenizer        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-wddx             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-xml              7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
un  php7.1-xmlreader        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-xmlrpc           7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            XMLRPC-EPI module for PHP
un  php7.1-xmlwriter        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.1-xsl              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.1-zip              7.1.33-16+ubuntu amd64            Zip module for PHP
ii  php7.2                  7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 all              server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metap
ii  php7.2-bz2              7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            bzip2 module for PHP
un  php7.2-calendar         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-cgi              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-cli              7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting langu
ii  php7.2-common           7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            documentation, examples and common module for PHP
un  php7.2-ctype            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-curl             7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            CURL module for PHP
un  php7.2-dom              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-exif             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-fileinfo         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-fpm              7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-C
un  php7.2-ftp              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-gd               7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            GD module for PHP
un  php7.2-gettext          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-iconv            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-json             7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            JSON module for PHP
ii  php7.2-mbstring         7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            MBSTRING module for PHP
ii  php7.2-mysql            7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            MySQL module for PHP
un  php7.2-mysqli           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-mysqlnd          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-opcache          7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            Zend OpCache module for PHP
un  php7.2-pdo              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-pdo-mysql        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-phar             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-posix            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-readline         7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            readline module for PHP
un  php7.2-shmop            <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-simplexml        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-sockets          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-sodium           <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-sysvmsg          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-sysvsem          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-sysvshm          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-tokenizer        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-wddx             <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-xml              7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP
un  php7.2-xmlreader        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-xmlwriter        <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.2-xsl              <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  php7.2-zip              7.2.31-1+ubuntu1 amd64            Zip module for PHP
un  php7.3-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  php7.4-imagick          <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20131226         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20151012         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20160303         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20170718         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20180731         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpapi-20190902         <none>           <none>           (no description available)
un  phpgacl                 <none>           <none>           (no description available)
ii  phpmyadmin              4:4.6.6-5        all              MySQL web administration tool
```

Comment: Your screenshot looks like a fresh install of WordPress with the Twenty Twenty theme; please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/369072/edit) to explain what you mean when you say "not loading properly". You also seem to be running PHP 7.1 on Apache, and 7.2 in the command line.

Comment: I couldn't find a good correct screenshot but I'm fairly sure that the bottom bit is not meant to be in a dual column type. I'm not sure how to debug that difference.

Comment: nevermind, it looks like I was mistaken that there was a problem. This post stemmed from other problems that were solved, though; so I'll update my post with those issues and how I solved them.